# Does video.js support MPEG2-TS/UDP streams?

Tags: video.js

I am just starting to play around with video.js and really like it. I currently have some code where I have two players showing two different HLS streams in a single browser page.

However, HLS inherently has high latency and that may not work for my project.  So I am wondering if video.js can receive and play MPEG2-TS/UDP streams which would have less latency (I can easily change the format of all of my source video steams).

My basic requirement is to have 2 players in a single browser page, one player showing the video stream sent from a particular network node, and the second showing how a different network node received that same stream. So the two video.js players on the browser page are showing 2 video streams that are actually the same video so they are highly correlated. This is why the latency is a critical requirement for this project.

Thanks,
-Andres